Configure Label and Circular Progress Bar in Init vs layoutSubviews
I'm working on a speed test app which has a custom CircularProgressView that includes a speedLabel and the speedLabel is centered in the progress view.
I have a createCircularPath method to create the progress view's path and I call it inside of layoutSubviews.
When I configure the speedLabel in the custom view's init and run the speed test then the speedLabel text and the progressTrack is updating as expected as the test is running. But if I configure the speedLabel in layoutSubviews together with the circular path than neither of them are being updated.
I have tried playing with it by changing the z-scores. I've also tried embedding the circular path, progressLayer and trackLayer inside another view then adding the view and label as subviews, but still the progress and speed are not being updated during the speed test when configured inside the layoutSubviews.
Looking for an explanation as to why this is.
Screen captures of working progress (when speedLabel configured in init):


And when when speedLabel configured in layoutSubviews the label and progress just stay static. Below is code when both configured in layoutSubviews
import UIKit

class CircularProgressView: UIView {
    
    var progressLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    var trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    var speedLabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        createCircularPath()
        configureSpeedLabel()
    }
    
    var progressColor = UIColor.white {
        didSet {
            progressLayer.strokeColor = progressColor.cgColor
        }
    }
    
    var trackColor = UIColor.white {
        didSet {
            trackLayer.strokeColor = trackColor.cgColor
        }
    }
    
    var speed = 0 {
        didSet {
            speedLabel.text = String(speed)
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate func configureSpeedLabel() {
        speedLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        speedLabel.text = String(speed)
        speedLabel.font = UIFont(name: "TimesNewRomanPSMT", size: 24)
        speedLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        speedLabel.isOpaque = true
        self.addSubview(speedLabel)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            speedLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
            speedLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }
    fileprivate func createCircularPath() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.width/2
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.width/2, y: frame.height/2), radius: (frame.width - 1.5)/2, startAngle: CGFloat(-0.5 * .pi), endAngle: CGFloat(1.5 * .pi), clockwise: true)
        trackLayer.path = path.cgPath
        trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        trackLayer.strokeColor = trackColor.cgColor
        trackLayer.opacity = 0.3
        trackLayer.lineWidth = 10.0
        trackLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0
        self.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)

        progressLayer.path = path.cgPath
        progressLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        progressLayer.strokeColor = progressColor.cgColor
        progressLayer.lineWidth = 10.0
        progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0
        self.layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
    }

}


Please show a [mcve]. What does the "Run Speed Test" button do to the CircularProgressView?

@Sweeper it runs a speed test - here's an mp4 of the simulation when clicking on "Run Speed Test". But the core of what I am asking is regarding why the label obscures the progress bar when I place it in layoutSubviews as opposed to inside init.

Adding subviews and layers from layoutSubviews() is a very bad idea.
We want to configure the label properties and add it as a subview, and configure the layers properties and add them as sublayers, when We initialize the view.
Then, in layoutSubviews(), we know the frame of the view (it will be called again if the frame changes), and we can define the path and the view's corner radius.
Then in the "set-able" properties (colors, speed, etc), we only need to update the related element properties.
Quick modification to your class...

CircularProgressView class
class CircularProgressView: UIView {
    
    var progressLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    var trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    var speedLabel = UILabel()
    
    var progressColor = UIColor.white {
        didSet {
            progressLayer.strokeColor = progressColor.cgColor
        }
    }
    
    var trackColor = UIColor.white {
        didSet {
            trackLayer.strokeColor = trackColor.cgColor
        }
    }
    
    // assuming we are setting the speed to an Int value
    //  between 0 and 100
    var speed: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            // don't exceed 100
            let spd: Int = min(speed, 100)
            speedLabel.text = String(spd)
            progressLayer.strokeEnd = CGFloat(spd) / 100.0
        }
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() {
        createCircularPath()
        configureSpeedLabel()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // this is where we know the frame of the view (self)
        // so here we can define the corner radius and the path
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.width/2
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.width/2, y: frame.height/2), radius: (frame.width - 1.5)/2, startAngle: CGFloat(-0.5 * .pi), endAngle: CGFloat(1.5 * .pi), clockwise: true)
        trackLayer.path = path.cgPath
        progressLayer.path = path.cgPath
    }
    
    fileprivate func configureSpeedLabel() {
        // this all only needs to be done once -- on init
        //  the only thing that will change is the text
        speedLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        speedLabel.text = String(speed)
        speedLabel.font = UIFont(name: "TimesNewRomanPSMT", size: 24)
        speedLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        speedLabel.isOpaque = true
        self.addSubview(speedLabel)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            speedLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
            speedLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }
    fileprivate func createCircularPath() {
        // this all only needs to be done once -- on init
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        // set the initial properties
        trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        trackLayer.strokeColor = trackColor.cgColor
        trackLayer.opacity = 0.3
        trackLayer.lineWidth = 10.0
        trackLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0
        
        progressLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        progressLayer.strokeColor = progressColor.cgColor
        progressLayer.lineWidth = 10.0
        progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0

        // add these sublayers
        self.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
        self.layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
    }
    
}


Example Controller class
class CPVExampleViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let cpv = CircularProgressView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        cpv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(cpv)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            cpv.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            cpv.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            cpv.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 280.0),
            cpv.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cpv.widthAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if cpv.speed >= 100 {
            cpv.speed = 0
        } else {
            cpv.speed += 10
        }
    }
}


Result:

Each tap anywhere will increment the .speed by 10 -- until we get to 100 and then it will reset to 0

Edit - in response to comments...
If we go back to your original code, and add a line:
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    
    // add this line
    print(#function)
    
    createCircularPath()
    configureSpeedLabel()
}

Then watch the output in the debug console.
You'll see that every time the label width changes - such as going from 9MB to 10MB to 9MB etc... layoutSubviews() is triggered.
Your code once-again calls createCircularPath (), which itself executes progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0
Now, you could get around that by:
speedLabel.textAlignment = .center

speedLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0)

but... it's possible that something else going on with the UI could cause layoutSubviews() to be called again.
As a general rule... handle initialization during init and handle layout in layoutSubviews (kinda makes sense, based on the naming).

appreciate the depth you went into. I'm not seeing the distinction you're making though - why just move the path and radius defs to the layoutSubviews? Especially since it is static in this instance? Or is that in case it does need to be dynamic and layoutSubviews can be called to update?

@brunshte -- see the Edit to my answer.

@brunshte - did that explanation make sense?
